# Module not found when trying to submit a python project

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I'm running Spark 2.2.0 on yarn, trying to submit python file `backtest.py` with all the project files zipped to `prediction.zip`. See below the spark submit command.

The problem is that Spark cant find one of my modules. 
What am I missing?

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive" \
SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7" \
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" \
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/bin/python" \
sudo -u hdfs \
/opt/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2001" \
--conf "spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0" \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--master yarn \
--py-files /home/gals/prediction.zip \
/home/gals/parent/prediction/backtesting/backtest.py
```

Comment: Please let me know if you want some more info...

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157793/spark-runs-in-local-but-cant-find-file-when-running-in-yarn/47159165#47159165) ? In general, make sure your zip and your python file is hosted somewhere accessible to all nodes, not on your machine.